# Create a function that finds dates and split them into pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dictionary

I have a `data` dataframe with about 70 columns. My interest is in the column `IDX` (which is the unique identifier for each record) and `Text` (which contains very long strings that are not very useful except to get the dates. The task is to get the dates, ensure that they are valid and create a column for each date. Often times, there are between 0 - 4 dates per `IDX`:`Text` pair

This is what I've got so far and it's taking forever to run, I need a better solution.

```
data:
IDX    RID      Text
100    10      6/26/06 begin tramadol, penicilin X 6 CYCLES. 1000mg tylenol X 1 YR after 11/2007
101    20      7/17/06-advil, qui;
102    10      7/19/06-ibuprofen. 8/31/06-penicilin, tramadol;
103    40      9/26/06-penicilin, tramadol;
104    91      5/23/06-penicilin, amoxicilin, tylenol;
105    84      10/20/06-ibuprofen, tramadol;
106    17      12/19/06-vit D, tramadol. 12/1/09 -6/18/10 vit D only for 5 months. 3/7/11 f/up
107    23      12/19/06-vit D, tramadol; 12/1/09 -6/18/10 vit D; 3/7/11 video follow-up
108    15      Follow up appt. scheduled
109    69      talk to care giver
110    32      12/15/06-2/16/07 everyday Follow-up; 6/8/16 discharged after 2 months
111    70      12/1/06?Follow up but no serious allergies
112    70      12/12/06-tylenol, vit D,advil; 1/26/07 scheduled surgery but had to cancel due to severe allergic reactions to advil

data_Dict = data.set_index('IDX')['Text'].to_dict()
def find_Date(df, data_Dict):
    Dates ={}
    for k, v in data_Dict.items():
        date_V = v
        matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(date_V))
        if len(matches) > 0:
            date_ = [format(matches[i], "%m/%d/%Y") for i in range(0,len(matches))]
        else:
            date_ = []
        date_.sort()
        Dates[k] = ', '.join([str(dates) for dates in date_])
        df['Dates'] = df['IDX'].map(Dates)
        date_types = pd.to_datetime(df["Dates"], errors='coerce')
        try:
            if date_types[0]:
                df['Date1'] = df['IDX'].map(date_types[0])
            elif date_types[1]:
                df['Date2'] = df['IDX'].map(date_types[1])
            elif date_types[2]:
                df['Date3'] = df['IDX'].map(date_types[2])
            elif date_types[3]:
                df['Date4'] = df['IDX'].map(date_types[3])
        except:
            print ("invalid date")
        df = df.drop('Dates', 1)
```

Still can't get this to produce an output...

```
def find_Date_(df):
    pd.to_datetime(df.set_index('IDX')['Text'].str.extractall('(\d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/]\d{2})')[0],errors='coerce').dropna().unstack().rename(columns=lambda x: x + 1).add_prefix('Date')

find_Date_(data)
```

Thank you all!

Comment: @piRSquared Edited. Thanks for bringing my attntion to that. It's a copy and paste omission :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not exactly sure what you're after...
... But this finds all things that might be a date, tries to parse it, then returns the first one that is successfully parses.

```
pd.to_datetime(
    data.set_index('IDX')['Text'].str.extractall(
        '(\d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/]\d{2})'
    )[0],
    errors='coerce'
).dropna().unstack()[0]

IDX
100   2006-06-26
101   2006-07-17
102   2006-07-19
103   2006-09-26
104   2006-05-23
105   2006-10-20
106   2006-12-19
107   2006-12-19
110   2006-12-15
111   2006-12-01
112   2006-12-12
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

To keep all parsed dates

```
pd.to_datetime(
    data.set_index('IDX')['Text'].str.extractall(
        '(\d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/]\d{2})'
    )[0],
    errors='coerce'
).dropna().unstack()

match          0          1          2          3
IDX                                              
100   2006-06-26        NaT        NaT        NaT
101   2006-07-17        NaT        NaT        NaT
102   2006-07-19 2006-08-31        NaT        NaT
103   2006-09-26        NaT        NaT        NaT
104   2006-05-23        NaT        NaT        NaT
105   2006-10-20        NaT        NaT        NaT
106   2006-12-19 2009-12-01 2010-06-18 2011-03-07
107   2006-12-19 2009-12-01 2010-06-18 2011-03-07
110   2006-12-15 2007-02-16 2016-06-08        NaT
111   2006-12-01        NaT        NaT        NaT
112   2006-12-12 2007-01-26        NaT        NaT
```

---

To get your desired column names

```
pd.to_datetime(
    data.set_index('IDX')['Text'].str.extractall(
        '(\d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/]\d{2})'
    )[0],
    errors='coerce'
).dropna().unstack().rename(columns=lambda x: x + 1).add_prefix('Date')

match      Date1      Date2      Date3      Date4
IDX                                              
100   2006-06-26        NaT        NaT        NaT
101   2006-07-17        NaT        NaT        NaT
102   2006-07-19 2006-08-31        NaT        NaT
103   2006-09-26        NaT        NaT        NaT
104   2006-05-23        NaT        NaT        NaT
105   2006-10-20        NaT        NaT        NaT
106   2006-12-19 2009-12-01 2010-06-18 2011-03-07
107   2006-12-19 2009-12-01 2010-06-18 2011-03-07
110   2006-12-15 2007-02-16 2016-06-08        NaT
111   2006-12-01        NaT        NaT        NaT
112   2006-12-12 2007-01-26        NaT        NaT
```

Comment: what I want is a list of all the dates that's successfully parsed per IDX. Then for each date in the list, put them in separate columns

Comment: I have columns `Date1`, `Date2`, `Date3` and `Date4`. An IDX with a list of 2 dates will have date values in cols `Date1` and `Date2` only

Comment: so when I run this code, I'm getting this error `
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'extractall'`

Comment: @CodeLearner I think I fixed it

Comment: Thank you. Though I haven't tested it yet. Will update you when I do. :) BTW I've accepted the solution.